# Ransack: return nothing when form submitted and no search values entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have the search form and the results of the search posted on the same page.

As I understand it: the default for ransack is that if a form is submitted with no values inputted into the search fields, then **all** records of that particular resource are returned.

How can I change it so that if a user does a search where they enter no values into the search fields, then **none** of the records are returned?

[Ransack Documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack)

This doesn't work:

```
if params["q"].values.present? # Always returns true because an array of empty strings returns true from method call: present?
  # do this
else
  # do that
end
```

Neither does this:

```
if params["q"].values.empty? # Always returns true because an array of empty strings returns true from method call: empty?
  # do this
else
  # do that
end
```

Checking for `params["q"].present?` does not work either because every time a form is submitted, whether there are values entered or not, this is what gets passed through to the server:

```
# showing with pry
[1] pry> params[:q] 
  => {"namesearch_start"=>"",
      "city_cont"=>"",
     }
[2] pry> params[:q].present?
  => true # always returns true
```

So `params["q"]` will always be present, whether there are values entered or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is reject any values that are blank.

```
if params[:q].reject { |_, v| v.blank? }.any? # .none? for inverted
  # Handle search
else
  # Handle no query scenario
end
```

Or

```
if params[:q].values.reject(&:blank?).any? # .none? for inverted
  # Handle search
else
  # Handle no query scenario
end
```

Comment: This works for the first request, but unfortunately for all other requests it does not work.  Example: User puts in a search value of `foo` for a field and clicks search. After results returned, user removes `foo` (no search values now) and clicks search again.  The `params[:q]` will be present, even though there are no values, so then the default behavior kicks in:  All the records are returned.

Comment: `present?` and `blank` will check that the key *has a value*, so if `params[:q]` is empty, you get a `false` for `present?` and `true` for `blank?`, and you can decide what to do accordingly. You can defer to Ransack only if the condition returns the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here's an alternative:

The ransack method returns a new instance of a Search class, https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/main/lib/ransack/adapters/active_record/base.rb

Looking at the Search class, https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/main/lib/ransack/search.rb, we see the inspect method is being overriden to create a better representation of the object. That representation includes a conditional based on any scoped arguments.

So, if you're using @q as the resource, as outlined in the docs like this:

```
    @q = MyModel.ransack(params[:q])
```

You can check if it has scopes or conditions with include:

```
    @q.inspect.include?('scope') || @q.inspect.include?('conditions')
```

or regex

```
    @q.inspect.match?(/scope|conditions/)
```

No search and empty searches will both evaluate to false as neither have scope or condition arguments.

Plus, as we're using the instance variable, we can use this check in both controllers and views.